# Disabling mouse hiding in Gnome Terminal while typing

Tags: terminal, mouse, gnome

Does anyone know how to turn off the hateful behavior that is now default in Gnome Terminal — when a key is pressed the mouse pointer hides until it is moved again.

I'm honestly ready to switch Linux distros to something Gnome-free after hours of trying to get this to not happen.   It's completely slowing me down / killing my productivity...

Comment: I'm on the latest Fedora, btw.

Comment: As someone who regularly uses multiple application windows in my workflow, I *completely* understand your frustration.

Rather than recompiling GNOME terminal (which really *should* be marked as the correct answer), I suggest you install ROXTerm: `sudo apt-get install roxterm` It was originally designed as a GNOME terminal but without the dependency on GNOME libraries.  It also hides the cursor in a more logical manner!

Comment: OMG.  Thanks so much, this is great.   (Didn't mark the answer below b/c never took the time to try it and verify that it worked!)

Comment: Also in light of comparing both side by side, I see what I /really/ wanted was for the cursor to always unhide on mouse move - not require a click - and not to disable hiding altogether.   Though @egmont's response still might answer my Q as asked...

Comment: gnome-terminal's intended behavior is the one you describe: Hide on keypress, unhide on mouse move. There's a bug that for some people it doesn't unhide. Unfortunately we can't reproduce it and there's no fix available yet.

Comment: It's the only terminal emulator I know that rewraps text on resize and the only reason I switched to it. And now I can't normally use it because of this bug. (does it have something to do with the fact that I use i3 window manager?)

Comment: The bad behavior (reported at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=725342) is caused by missing focus in/out events (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677329) which just got fixed in Gtk+: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=d55b815

Comment: @egmont Thanks for the followup!  I've been following the bug as well as any resolutions that is provided on this problem.  I'm glad for the update.  Do you think you can provide a link to how to use or apply the fixed/patched terminal?  Look at: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=725342#c82.

Comment: what the F! Yes this is it (Fedora 22), it hides the mouse and unless you click on it it does not appear. I use Cinnamon on Fedora, I abandoned most of gnome applications (editor is now useless) still used gnome-terminal, time to also ditch that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnome-terminal doesn't have an option to disable hiding the mouse cursor.  Moving the mouse will sometimes unhide it (not sure what the criterion is) and sometimes not.  Many times you have to (as you have already noticed) actually click on the Window to unhide it.  The problem with this is that if you have multiple terminal windows and multiple monitors, with the cursor hidden, you have no idea where you're clicking.

The resolution is to change the default terminal to a different emulator such as `xfece4-terminal` or as mentioned in the comment `roxterm`.

You'll also have to change the default terminal emulator to bring up your new configuration by default with:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'xfce4-terminal'
```

*(Change xface4-terminal in the command to your alternate emulator.)*

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in gnome-terminal: [Mouse cursor sometimes hides if Terminal is focused](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=725342)

The bug is now marked as `RESOLVED FIXED`, so it might soon reach your distribution:

> The fix has made it into the official Gtk+ 3.18.9 tarball, and in turn, has already appeared in Debian Unstable and in Ubuntu Xenial beta.

James' answer solves the problem, but for those unsure about messing up with their system, enduring the bug for a few more weeks until your distribution updates gnome-terminal is the safest option.